# How to extract dygraph plot parameters to R in a shiny app?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dygraphs

I am writting a mini-app in Shiny to explore time-series using Dygraphs library.

I would like to set an actionButton to 'freeze' the actual view of the graph and recover it whenever I want.

My first goal is to get the actual graphical parameters and save them into an R object. For example, to get the actual x-axis range I have to extract dateWindow() parameter. Unfortunately, I do not even know how to start, although I have read several documentation about it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more concrete? I worked with time series and dygraph. Indeed, if you specify all of details, I will help you how to develop your idea.

Comment: In this example (http://dygraphs.com/tests/is-zoomed-ignore-programmatic-zoom.html) they are shown the "Window coordinates" dateWindow and valueRange at real time. I would like to extract these coordinates into an R object when clicking a button, so as to save them and recover that particular view of the graph later. I suppose I have to create a javascript function for this but I do not really know how. Thanks in advance.